# Android service - broadcast - intent type

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcast

I need to build an application for Android devices and I have some questions. I don't have much experience in android.

My app runs on master - detail flow and I have a background TCP socket service. Right now i use bindService for ... easier communication between activity and service. The biggest problem I have right now is onDestroy() because I have to unbindService and I lose TCP connection (on orientation change)

The application contains 15 simple commands (each one with own activity) and 2 of them need to send continuous data from activity to service, what is the best approach for this? I also need some response from some of the socket commands.

Another idea is to broadcast messages between service - activity, but how I send data from activity - service.

Maybe I asked stupid questions, but I tried to search examples ... read documentation, there is a big fog in my brain, please advice & thanks

Comment: **"2 of them need to send continuous data from activity to service"** - What sort of data and why does it have to be continuous? Also how do you define continuous?

Comment: I send current touch position x - y, I send data only when activity is used and user touches the screen. sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: So why are you worried about a brief break in communication between the `Activity` and the `Service`? When you rotate an Android device, the `Activity` will be destroyed and recreated. DUring that time, it makes no sense to send xy touch coordinates to the `Service`. The `Service` itself isn't destroyed/recreated as a result of orientation change and should be able to maintain an open TCP connection - you simply need to bind to the `Service` again when the `Activity` is recreated.

Comment: If I bind the service to activity, on destroy - create another activity, the tcp service recreates life cycle so my tcp connection will be destroyed ... it will connect again, etc.

Comment: I searched more on internet and found EventBus and Otto, what do you think?

Comment: **"the tcp service recreates life cycle so my tcp connection will be destroyed ... it will connect again, etc"** - No. A `Service` will continue running until it is explicitly stopped - you can call `startService(...)` from as many activities as you want and only one instance of the `Service` will exist. Also, as I said, changing orientation of a device only destroys / recreates activities - any `Service` will continue to run.

Comment: Yes, I have to stop it on destroy, if not ... if user gets the app in background - not visible for long time, the service will eat battery. right?! I use unbindService